# Laravel display menu based on user roles

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, roles

I'm trying to find out if theres a BETTER way to display menu items based on the user's role. The below code works but i'm not sure if it's the right way. I made a CheckAdmin middleware and implemented the same code for displaying the menu.

**Tables**
1. users -> id,name,password
2. roles -> id, name
3. user_role -> user_id, role_id

**CheckAdmin middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $userRoles = Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name');
    if(!$userRoles->contains('Admin')){
        return redirect('/permission-denied');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

**HomeController**

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name');
    return view('home',compact('user'));

}
```

**View**

```
@if($user->contains('Admin'))
  <li>
    <a href="#">adminPage</a>
  </li>
@endif
@if($user->contains('User'))
  <li>
    <a href="#">userPage</a>
  </li>
@endif
```

Comment: Is it a package like Laratrust/ Entrust or you have made your own Role?

Comment: @zahidhasanemon no, no package installed

Comment: Referring to the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-contains you don't have to pluck.  ```Auth::user->roles->contains('Role');``` should work.